# Is it right to create am html5 game with Canvas or custom html structure

Tags: javascript, html, flash, canvas

I am trying to find out the best way of convering flash games into html5.

I built one game with custom html, css, js and had some issues with having the game fullscreen always on any desktop/mobile screen, audio issues on apple devices etc.

As far as i checked all html5 games are created with canvas. I am trying to understand if that is possible to create any type of flash game with canvas and avoid issues i had like to have the game fullscreen without any issues or custom coding, avoid audio issues.

Will it be possible to create any type of structure from flash game with the canvas?

I am new to Canvas so i need to know all pros and cons and see if the canvas performance will be better than the custom html one.

Also the game will have an API for the game logic so how easy it will be to integrate the game API with the canvas?

Mostly games are Slot machine games so i will need winning combinations logic, lots of animations.
Any help is apprecited.
Thanks.

Comment: HTML5 Canvas can create any shape or form Flash can, as well as play video/audio. You will be limited by the lack of a dedicated IDE like Adobe Flash has. Also your code will be in JavaScript so you have compatibility issues across browsers. With the cons out of the way, yes you can create anything in Canvas you can create in Flash. I recommend using a framework like Phaser.js or Pixi.js.

Comment: Hmm i see. The frameworks will help with what stuff? And what about the api integration. Will it be possible with canvas @EmilS.Jørgensen?

Comment: The framework helps with the limitations. API integration depends on your coding, not the framework. All of it is possible with canvas, but there are quite the difference between actionscript and javascript, and much of this depends on the developer.

Comment: So you are saying that the Pixi framework for example will not conflict with the game backend api and can be integrated easily. Mostly i will be creating Slot machine games so you say that all is possible to create with canvas @EmilS.Jørgensen? What you can say for the audio sounds so it will not be an issue with pixi framework?

Comment: If your backend accepts JavaScript generated HTTP requests, then no worries there. Pixi.js and Phaser.js are frontend only frameworks so they shouldn't interfere with the backend. Slot machine games are pretty easy to create and for audio you got the HTML5 Audio elements: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio. All this still assumes that you have a developer that knows JavaScript though.

Comment: You can find a step-by-step slot machine canvas guide here: https://bravenewmethod.com/2013/03/14/simple-slot-machine-with-html5/. (beware, it is a little outdated, but it highlights the important parts).

Comment: I know Javascript pretty well and i did my first game with JS, html custom code. thanks for the link, will check it out. And what about the fullscreen mode, will canvas solve th issue i had with resizing the game per screen and be always fullscreeen or resized @EmilS.Jørgensen?

Answer (score 0):

**Notice that this snippet wont work on stackoverflow because it's nested in an iframe**

Fullscreen is a standard feature with a rather wide support: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/requestFullScreen#Browser_compatibility

```js
var c = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("canvas"));
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
c.width = window.outerWidth;
c.height = window.outerHeight;
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.font = "120px Arial";
setInterval(function () {
    c.width = window.outerWidth;
    c.height = window.outerHeight;
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(" +
        (Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)) + "," +
        (Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)) + "," +
        (Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)) +
        ",0.5)";
    ctx.fillRect(Math.floor(Math.random() * c.width), Math.floor(Math.random() * c.height), Math.floor(Math.random() * c.width), Math.floor(Math.random() * c.height));
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.fillText("Click for fullscreen", Math.floor(c.width / 2), Math.floor(c.height / 2));
    ctx.strokeText("Click for fullscreen", Math.floor(c.width / 2), Math.floor(c.height / 2));
}, 1000 / 60);
c.onclick = function goFullScreen(evt) {
    if (c.requestFullscreen) {
        c.requestFullscreen();
    }
    else if (c.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
        c.webkitRequestFullScreen();
    }
    else if (c.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        c.mozRequestFullScreen();
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you fo r the nsippet. By saying fullscreen i mean always have the game without vertical scrolling so will the canvas be resized per screen and fit properly with its inner elements @Emil S. Jørgensen?

Comment: You can treat the canvas as an `img` tag for scaling concerns. You might need to listen for page resizes but it is definitely possible.

Comment: Hmm that's great. Cause i imagina that if i will have elemets positioned with coordinates and then just scale the canvas or make it to fit accordingly that will be very good. Thanks for the help and feedback @Emil S. Jørgensen. Will check and see